# VBA - Apply AutoFilter to All Sheets But in Different Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I need to apply a format and filter to 4 sheets in my workbook - for the first 3 sheets, the format and filter needs to be applied to column B and the last sheet in column C.

So I thought of doing this - where I search for a column header and if found, apply the formatting to that column and then apply the filter.

***Code:***

```
Sub DateFilter()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Current_Date As Date
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim WshtNames As Variant, WshtNameCrnt As Variant

    Set y = Workbooks("workbook.xlsm")

    For Each ws In y.Worksheets

        With ws

            bFound = False

            'Search for the Word "Status" on the first row of the Sheet
            Set StatusFound = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Employee End Date", LookAt:=xlWhole)

            'If Status is found then apply filter
            If Not StatusFound Is Nothing Then

                For a = .UsedRange.Columns.Count To 2 Step -1

                    If .Cells(1, a).Value = "Employee End Date" Then

                        'Loop through all celss in column B and change format to date
                        'For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Cells

                            Current_Date = CDate(a)
                            a.Value = Current_Date

                        'Next c


                        'Make all cells in column A "General" input
                        Columns(1).NumberFormat = "General"

                        ' Set the autofilter to display all dates other than yesterdays
                        ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date)), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date))

                        bFound = True

                    End If

                Next a

            End If
        End With
     Next

End Sub
```

But then on this line `a.Value = Current_Date` I also get an object defined error.

Note: In this last example, I have commented out the for loop within the If Statement as I thought it wasn't necessary for this situation.

Comment: In the second bit of code you don't assign a value to LastRow. In the last you are using `a` as an integer (for a loop) so makes no sense to assign a date to it.

Comment: @SJR Thank you for the reply.. I have updated my code for the first one where I do assign a value to LastRow (which is essentially the array - because that's where the sheet names are stored) and I still receive the same error. As for the second bit of code, I gathered I am using it the wrong way, but I am not quite sure how to adjust the code.

Comment: Maybe streamline your last bit of code a bit better: For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Col = WorksheetFunction.Match("Employee End Date", ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)), 0)
    Columns(Col).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy hh:mm"

Comment: OK,  I suggest slimming down your question. Instead of posting several blocks of code, stick to the one which you think is best and describe the problem with that.

Comment: Another thought - have a sub which has a column argument and pass the column depending on the sheet.

Comment: @JvdV Thank you for your reply. I have not tested your suggestion yet, but the answer jblood94 below seems to be doing the trick.. :)

Comment: @SJR Thank you for your reply. I have amended my question to slim it down a little and will keep this in mind for future posts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt was really close to what you wanted. Just clean it up a bit and use a second macro to call it up as many times as you need.

- Be explicit in your range references. `Columns(1).NumberFormat =
  "General"` was operating on the active sheet instead of on `ws`. Just
  add a period at the beginning since you're in a `With` statement:
  `.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "General"`.
- Operating on the data from large ranges one cell at a time is more
  efficient if you pull the data in as a variant array, perform the
  operations, then output the results as an array.

Here's my stab at it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DateFilterAll()
    With Workbooks("workbook.xlsm")
        DateFilter .Sheets("Sheet1"), 2
        DateFilter .Sheets("Sheet2"), 2
        DateFilter .Sheets("Sheet3"), 2
        DateFilter .Sheets("Sheet4"), 3
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub DateFilter(ws As Worksheet, iCol As Integer)
    'Initialize variables
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngCurrRow As Long
    Dim vDates() As Variant

    With ws
        'Find the last row with contents
        lngLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'get the values from column iCol
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, iCol), .Cells(lngLastRow, iCol))
        vDates = rng.Value

        'Loop through the values from column iCol and convert to date
        For lngCurrRow = 1 To lngLastRow - 1
            vDates(lngCurrRow, 1) = CDate(vDates(lngCurrRow, 1))
        Next lngCurrRow

        'output the date values
        rng = vDates

        'Make all cells in column A "General" input
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "General"

        ' Set the autofilter to display all dates other than yesterdays
        .Columns(iCol).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works like a charm :)